# While installing It stayed on "Detecting file systems" for about an hour is this usual?

Tags: software-installation

While I was trying to install Ubuntu(It's my first time)   The installation was on " Detecing file systems" for about an hour is this usual ? or there is something wrong I've done or is it a problem with the installation file

Comment: how big was your hard disk size?

Comment: 600 GB ( Total )

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?    See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM  
Did you select the media check before trying to install?
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: I've fixed it.    thanks anyway ( It was an interrupted file ) I downloaded it again and it works fine